# Is there a way to run Selenium tests on a web application in a real iOS device from Windows?

Tags: selenium, appium, remotewebdriver

With [Appium](http://appium.io/) it's possible to run selenium tests on Android and iOS, however for iOS you can only run the tests from a mac. I need to run my tests from a Windows machine. Furthermore I need to run the tests on a real device (iPhone and iPad) so alternatives like [ios-driver](https://ios-driver.github.io/ios-driver/) will not work for me.

Are there any drivers that can handle this?

Alternatively, I do have a mac which has been set up as a [RemoteWebDriverServer](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RemoteWebDriverServer). Today I use this to run my tests from Windows on OS X. Would it be possible to connect my RemoteWebDriver on Windows to iOS through the macbook using it's RemoteWebDriverServer? I do not wish to set up all of my tests and run them directly from the mac.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no OS X Emulator for Windows, there are for mac but in that case it wont be a windows machine. I don't see any reason not to succeed with you alternative approach, you should be able to setup tests to be initiated on a windows machine but to be executed on Mac via RemoteWebDriver.

Comment: How would I have to set up my driver in that case? When i run tests remotely on the mac i use `RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://my_mac_ip:4444/wd/hub"), caps);`, however when setting up a driver for iOS i would have to use the iOS device ip and the port 4723. So to connect to iOS through the mac i would somehow have to tell the driver to go into the first URL and then from there into the next?

Comment: To reach the Node(your Mac machine) you need to run the selenium server in node mode at the machine [link](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp#selenium-grid-2-0). Then all the other things you should pass in the driver capabilities when instantiating a remote web driver). [link](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RemoteWebDriver)